# String copy(strcpy)

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I have the following code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char * l;
*l = 'c';
*(l+1) = 'g';
*(l+2) = '\0';

char *second;
strcpy(second, l);
printf("string: %s\n", second);
}
```

When I run it is says:
The output says "Segmentation fault"....any suggestions??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`l` is an uninitialized pointer; you can't dereference it. You should allocate enough space to write its contents (statically (1) or dynamically (2)).

```
char l[3]; /* (1) */

#include <stdlib.h>
char *l = malloc(3); /* (2) */
```

It is the same error with `strcpy`: `second` is an unitialized pointer, you can't write into it.

Comment: this brings up another question? if I have char * ch; would this automatically allocate one memory location for me to store one character

Comment: No, if you have `char *ch`, it just allocates space to a pointer to `char`, and it remains unitialized. It you want to have a character, declare rather `char ch`.

Answer (score 0):

You will learn to despise the `Segmentation Fault` error...

It's usually called when you try to access memory that is not yours. Most common occurrence would be when you try to access an array index that is out of bounds.

`char *l` just creates a pointer to a char. What you want is a string, which in C is defined as an array of chars. So when you try to access the next location in memory of whatever `l` is pointing to (which will probably just be garbage), you're going to access memory that isn't yours, thus `Segmentation Fault`

Answer (score 0):

You could get memory with malloc or point the pointer to an already existing variable.

```
  char word[3];
  char *l;
  l = word;
```

Now you can do such assignments:

```
  *l = 'c';
  *(l+1) = 'g';
  *(l+2) = '\0';
```

but now that you want to copy it to another pointer, this pointer must be pointing to another string or you should allocate memory for it.

```
  char *pointer_to_second;
  char second[3];
  pointer_to_second = second;
```

or if you prefer to get dynamic memory, change the 3 lines above be this one bellow:

```
  char *pointer_to_second = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
```

after that you can do what you wanted:

```
  strcpy(pointer_to_second, l);
```

But remember, if you are using a C compiler you must declare all variables at the beggining, otherwise you will get an error. If you are using a C++ compiler you won't have to concern about it.

Segmentation fault happens when you try to access a field that doesn't belong to your vector. For example, if you try this:

```
  printf("The value in position 3 of my pointer is %c\n", *(l + 3));
```

You will probably get an error, because you pointer have 3 positions and you are trying to acess the 4th one.