# Parseing a C string (user input via console) with C string functions - segmentation fault

Tags: c, string-parsing

I'm trying to write a function that parses a string (a `char *`) character at a time but for some reason I am receiving a segmentation fault. I'm trying to read in user input and have it parsed for the program name and the arguments but that's somewhat irreverent.

Console:

```
>./mish 
>mish>ls
>command start:ls 
>*tempCommand:l 
>bottom
>Segmentation fault
```

Code:

```
    ParserData parseCommand(ParserData parserData, char* command)
    {
        char* tempCommand;
        char* currToken = '\0';
        short firstSpace = 0;

        printf("command start:%s \n", command);

        strcpy(tempCommand, command);

        while(*tempCommand)
        {
            printf("*tempCommand:%c \n", *tempCommand);

            if((char)*tempCommand == ' ' && firstSpace == 0)
            {
               printf("currToken: %c \n", (char)*currToken);
               strcpy(parserData.myChildProgramName,currToken);
               printf("after:");
               currToken = '\0';
               firstSpace = 1;
            }
            else if((char)*tempCommand != ' ' && *tempCommand != '-')
            {
              //strcat(currToken, tempCommand); 
            }

            printf("bottom\n");

            printf("currToken: %c \n", *currToken);

            tempCommand++;

       }

       printf("out\n");
       parserData.myChildProgramArguments = currToken;

      return parserData;
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [String copy(strcpy)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996604/string-copystrcpy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tempCommand` is an unitialised `char*` when:

```
strcpy(tempCommand, command);
```

is called, causing the segmentation fault as `strcpy()` will be writing somewhere it should not. Allocate memory for `tempCommand` before calling `strcpy()`:

```
tempCommand = malloc(strlen(command) + 1); /* +1 for terminating null. */
if (tempCommand)
{
    /* Use 'tempCommand' */
}
```

Remember to `free(tempCommand);` when no longer required.

There is no reason to cast the value of `*curToken` or `*tempCommand` to a `char` as that is already the type.

Comment: why the +1? for the null character?

Comment: @Katianie, yes it is for null.

Comment: and am I using the while correctly or are u suggesting to do it like the if statement here.

Comment: @Katianie, the `while` terminating condition is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically allocate memory to the tempCommand variable using malloc.

Something like:

```
tempCommand = malloc(sizeof(command));
```

This should do the trick.  Good luck!

Comment: This is incorrect as `sizeof(command)` is the `sizeof(char*)`, which is not enough.